# Summation of series 1/2 -3/4 5/6 -7/8......n

Tags: sum-of-digits

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n=1,num;
float x=0,m;
printf("Enter no. of digits:\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
for(n=1;n<=num;n++)
{
    m=(float)(2*n-1)/2*n;
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        m=m*(-1);
    }
    x+=m;
}
    printf("Summation is:\n%.4f\n\n",x);
}
```

**I wanted to print the series 1/2 -3/4 5/6 -7/8......num where num is accepted by user. Its going pretty well when num is 1. But doesn't work correctly for any other value of num. Please help!**

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: By giving input as 2,answer should be -0.25. But -2.5 is coming.

Comment: And what debugging have you done? Have you narrowed down where the data becomes off?

Comment: I'm a beginner. I don't know debugging.

Comment: Every programmer needs to understand debugging; it's one of the most important skills you can have. It's also expected that you've debugged before you ask for help here. Work the math out on paper to get your expected result, then figure out where the numbers in the program differ from the math you worked out manually.

Comment: Ok i got the solution.Thanks for suggestion.